# Installing new crontab leads to premature EOF error

Tags: linux, cron

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/) on how to install a crontab scheduling a job to run every 10 minutes, but I'm running into an issue.

My Cron table is

```
*/10 * * * * /app/qa/dashboard/ec2/autoscaling-onesearch/manage check
```

But I'm getting this error after saving it:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.XXXXI5bw3p":1: premature EOF
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit?
```

I'm using `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 (Tikanga)` if that helps.

I've tried adding quotes around the path, but no dice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, Emacs was adding some sort of funky characters at the end according to the "EOF"...

I used vi instead:

```
$ export VISUAL=vi
$ crontab -e
```

then used the same cron.  Saved/Quit, and it worked just fine.  Weird.